# Flutter - Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider

Tags: image, flutter, share, androidx, permission-denied

I'm trying to make my flutter app to share an image file in external storage. I've used several plugins to share it and they all result to the same error "Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider".

I've tried dozens of Provider additions to the Manifest with several filepaths.xml and still doesn't work.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading 
androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri 
content://com.example.fluttersharefile/images/image.png from pid=1769, 
uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
E/DatabaseUtils( 2116):     at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:729)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2116):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:602)E/DatabaseUtils( 2116):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceFilePermission(ContentProvider.java:593)
```

E/DatabaseUtils( 2116):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:507)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2116):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:307)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2116):     at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2116):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)

I've also tried to request for Storage permission manually using permission handler plugin and it still makes no difference

Any help?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I had same issue right now